# Extension functor through trace of endofunctor

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

I have a certain construction which I believe have been studied before, I just don't know where to look

Let $C, D$ be categories and $U: D \to C$ a functor
The category of $U$-extensions is the following:
Objects: pairs $(F, \eta)$ where $F:C\to D$ is a functor and $\eta: id_{End(C)}\Rightarrow UF$ is a natural transformation

Morphisms $(F_1, \eta_1) \to (F_2, \eta_2)$ are natural transformations $\xi:F_1\Rightarrow F_2$ commuting with the eta's: $\xi \eta_1 = \eta_2$

What is the real name of this category, what has been investigated about it?

Comment: Can you give us a little more detail about the specific context where such things appear, or give an example?

Comment: @Berci This is a general notion of extensing one category into another. For example, not every abelian group is the addative structure of a ring so instead we can ask what is the minimal change (some morphism of groups) one has to make to turn a group into a ring, and the question is exactly to classify this extension category for the forgetful functor from rings to groups

Comment: Well, the *left adjoint* of $U$ - if exists -, with the unit of adjunction as $\eta$, is a special object in your category, and this alone turns an Abelian group into a ring, freely.

Comment: @Berci Seems reasonable, I'm looking for deeper results, I can think about a lot of questions on this category such that the answer can get very complicated. Do you know a name for it? Maybe this is more appropriate for math stackexchange?

Comment: * math overflow

Comment: This is a comma category of the same "shape" of those used for universal arrows. In this case, $id_C\downarrow U^C$ where $id_C$ is being viewed as an object of the functor category $[C,C]$. Presumably you wanted $U\xi$, i.e. $U\xi\circ\eta_1=\eta_2$.

Comment: @DerekElkins This doesn't make sense, $U\xi\circ\eta_1:U\Rightarrow UF_2$. Did you mean $U\xi\circ\eta_1=U\eta_2$? If so, this is not what I want as the idea here is to study the functors to $D$ themselves, i.e. the different $D$ structures over a given object, and taking this condition of equalizing after applying $U$ "loses information" of different $D$ structures on the same object

Comment: @DerekElkins I now see my error, this does work as an alternate definition, thank you. You can write it up as an answer so I'll approve